# validationEngine and dropdowns

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, jquery-validation-engine

I'm trying to get validationEngine to work when I addClass dynamically via a dropdown select. I want to remove the validation class for some fields and add it to others based on a drop down selection.

I'm able to do the following:

```
if (jQuery("#ValidTemplateSelection :selected").val() == 'FC') {
      jQuery("#ValidSelection-fc").addClass("validate[required] text-input");
      jQuery("#ValidSelection-qmi").removeClass("validate[required] text-input");
      jQuery("#templateform").validationEngine();
} 
if (jQuery("#ValidTemplateSelection :selected").val() == 'QMI') {
      jQuery("#ValidSelection-qmi").addClass("validate[required] text-input");
      jQuery("#ValidSelection-fc").removeClass("validate[required] text-input");
      jQuery("#templateform").validationEngine('detach');
      jQuery("#templateform").validationEngine();
}
return false;
```

AddClass and removeClass both work fine.

Validation is successful on first selection. However when choosing a different option, addClass adds the class but the validation does not happen. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to detach and then re-instantiate validationengine? I was doing something similar where I add and remove a class dynamically, and I only instantiate validationengine the once when the document is ready. This was with two email fields though, not a combo-box. See the [validationengine forums](http://validationengine.vanillaforums.com/discussion/64/validate-an-empty-non-mandatory-fiel).

Try it without detaching and re-instantiating validationengine, just instantiate validationengine once on document ready.

~Cyrix

Comment: I was able to redefine my approach to the problem by re-engineering the entire thing to load up a new script via ajax load.

Comment: Wow, seems overkill because I managed to get it working just by adding and removing classes, in much the same way you first attempted. Oh well, the main thing is it's working!